# A Shop can have Products from a Supplier

Tags: mysql, database-design, erd

I'm creating a Platform where Suppliers have Products that Shops can choose, add to their Shop and start selling.

My situation is as follows:

- A Supplier can have many Products (for example: 'T-shirt', 'Iphone Case') (**Supplier->product: One-To-Many**)
- A Supplier Product can have many SKU (for instance: 'T-shirt Small Black', 'T-Shirt Small White') (**Product->sku: One-To-Many**)
- A Shop should be able to "copy" Products from the Supplier, So would I need a Shop_Product table here? (**Shop->Product: One-To-Many**)

The main problem is that my Shop has SKU's from the Supplier but no Products. If I add a Shop_Products table representing a relationshhip, then how should I "couple" my Shop_Skus to that table?

### Should I add a Shop_Product table, next to the existing Shop_Sku table?

My current database structure is depicted in the diagram below:

[image]

With a Shop_Product column it would look like this

[image]

But then there is no relationship between the Shop_Product and the Shop_Sku which makes this structure irrelevant.

Any help is welcome!